# Minitest: verify an external URL with an integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, minitest

I have a flow in my app where I have to send users to an external site (in this case, LinkedIn) to download a CSV of their data. LinkedIn seems to change the page every few months, enough that my instructions become obsolete. I'm using minitest, and would like to write a simple integration test to monitor for specific text on LinkedIn's page so that the test fails if they change the page.

What I'd like to do is something like:

```
test 'linkedin_page' do
  get 'https://www.linkedin.com/psettings/member-data'
  assert_response :success
  assert_match "Download an archive of your account data", response.body
end
```

When I run the above code, I get:
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] "/psettings/member-data", so it's ignoring the domain and trying to get the URI on my local app.

How can I run an integration test on an external URL?

Comment: I don't think you can (note: I could be wrong). From what I recall, you can test that you are sent to another URL (because you're still testing something that the local server is doing... ie preparing a "redirect to" with the given URL)... but following that redirect offsite is a bit of an unusual case. You might be able to do that with a browser-based tool like selenium/watir (or whatever is flavour-of-the-month nowadays).

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that might be the case.

Comment: You might be able to set up something like "pingdom" to test that the page is reachable? (note: i'm not overly familiar with pingdom but I know we use it to test that our servers are set up and responding correctly).

Comment: You cannot do it in controller test. Try it in integration test